# Failed to load package in Dart

Tags: dart, google-chrome-app

When I try to import a package with the syntax `import 'package:markdown/markdown.dart';`, I get no error in Dart Editor but when I run the dart application, the debugger shows me the message:

```
An error occurred loading file: package:markdown/markdown.dart
Failed to load resource
  chrome-extension://gfjabgeipkcfopofkhjimepepnomcidk/dart/packages/markdown/markdown.dart
```

But when I write the whole path (`import "../../packages/markdown/markdown.dart";`) everything works fine. I cannot understand why the syntax `package:` doesn't work in my code though it works in Dart Editor's own examples.

You can see the Chrome app architecture below (I'm loading a package from `translator.dart`):

[image: Application architecture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have the package added as a dependency in pubspec.yaml (which I assume you do).

Also try running following:

- delete packages folder
- delete pubspec.lock
- run pub get to fetch the
  dependencies again.

Comment: Thanks! Just one thing if someone reads this post later: the packages folder to delete is the first (with path `dart/packages` in my case).

Answer (score 0):

I think in your md_to_html folder you need a link to the 'packages' directory for the shortform to work. I seem to remember this happening when the workspace is built but I'm not sure now which command triggers it, have a look at the current pub docs.